# Outlook REST API sync messages: no deltaLink in last response

Tags: office365api, outlook-restapi, outlook-api

I'm using Outlook REST API v2.0, and follow instructions from docs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations#synchronize-messages

Everything goes fine, I send `Prefer: odata.track-change` header with initial and "delta" requests, receive `Preference-Applied: odata.track-changes` with initial response (not with "delta" or "skip" responses), receive `nextLink` while there still are messages to sync, **but** when round is over, docs say I should receive `deltaLink`, which I can use in following rounds, but I don't receive it.

Here I print request url, count of received messages and keys of parsed json response:

```
<<<< init url: https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/users/UserX@myorg.onmicrosoft.com/MailFolders/Inbox/messages
>> init messages: 100
>> init keys: [u'@odata.deltaLink', u'@odata.context', u'value']

<<<<<<< https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/users/UserX@myorg.onmicrosoft.com/MailFolders/Inbox/messages/?%24deltatoken=x6ACBKs7JAHtb4FNhCplyPMw9QUAAGlsP20BAAAA
>> messages: 100
>> response keys: [u'@odata.nextLink', u'@odata.context', u'value']

<<<<<<< https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/users/UserX@myorg.onmicrosoft.com/MailFolders/Inbox/messages/?%24skipToken=x6ACAqs7JAHtb4FNhCplyPMw9QUAAGlsP20CAAAA
>> messages: 100
>> response keys: [u'@odata.nextLink', u'@odata.context', u'value']

<<<<<<< https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/users/UserX@myorg.onmicrosoft.com/MailFolders/Inbox/messages/?%24skipToken=x6ACAqs7JAHtb4FNhCplyPMw9QUAAGlsP20DAAAA
>> messages: 100
>> response keys: [u'@odata.nextLink', u'@odata.context', u'value']

<<<<<<< https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/users/UserX@myorg.onmicrosoft.com/MailFolders/Inbox/messages/?%24skipToken=x6ACAqs7JAHtb4FNhCplyPMw9QUAAGlsP20EAAAA
>> messages: 93
>> response keys: [u'@odata.context', u'value']
```

As you can see I also use `x-AnchorMailbox` impersonation, but it's not explicitly prohibited.

So, am I doing something wrong, or this API is broken?

Comment: I just tested it and had no problem. To be clear, are you sending the Prefer header (with odata.track-changes and odata.maxpagesize) with every request?

Comment: I send `prefer: odata.track-changes` with "initial" and "delta" requests. I tried both provide and skip `maxpagesize` -- same behaviour.

Comment: Ok, added `prefer: odata.track-changes` to all requests and now it works. Text and examples in documentation both say it's not needed with `skipToken` request, which is a misinformation.

Comment: Thanks! I'll pass this along to the docs folks so we can get it corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out, despite docs in texts and examples say you don't send `Prefer: odata.track-changes` header with `skipToken` requests, you have to do that to receive `deltaToken'.

[image]